# MongoDB: sort, but with with a specific document first in the results?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

The requirement, set by MGMT and sales of course, is that query results should contain a specific document as the first result, then all other documents matching the query.

Here is a very simplified example of my data:

```
{ _id: 1,
title: 'other item',
category: 'show'
}
{ _id: 2,
title: 'THE ITEM THAT MUST BE RETURNED FIRST',
category: 'show'
}
{ _id: 3,
title: 'other item 2',
category: 'show'
}
{ _id: 4,
title: 'item not matching query',
category: 'hide'
}
```

I have been passed a value of `id`, `{ _id : 2 }` in this example, in an http request body, and I need to query for all other documents matching some criteria, `{ category: 'show' }` in this example, but the article with `id == 2` needs to be the first document returned:

```
//pseudo-code. I know this is not even close
itemsCollection.aggregate([
{ $match : { category: 'show'} }
// sort, but with item with id == 2 at top, and the rest sorted by title ASC
{ $sort : { {item_with_id_2: first_returned }, {title: 1} }
])
```

The above is pseudo-code for what I need the result to look like:

```
{ _id: 2,
title: 'THE ITEM THAT MUST BE RETURNED FIRST',
category: 'show'
}
{ _id: 1,
title: 'other item',
category: 'show'
}
{ _id: 3,
title: 'other item 2',
category: 'show'
}
```

How do I force a single specific document, whose `id` I do have, to the top of the results of a query?

Comment: you can try eventually during aggregation early stage  to add a predefined field ("sort_key") having values 0 for the _id: 2 and 1 for all the rest ...and then furter on to use it for sorting the values in the way you want.Is not nice but it does the trick , I guess.Maybe this can help: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
itemsCollection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "category": 1,
      "title": 1,
      "priority": {
        "$eq": [
          "$_id",
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "priority": -1
    }
  }
])
```

Essentially we're creating a synthetic attribute, `priority`, that gets set to `true` when `_id` is a match. Finally, we sort by `priority` to return the matches - the documents that match by `_id`, will be on top, followed by the rest.

Comment: This is what I needed. For anyone researching this problem after the fact: the `"priority" : { "$eq" : ["$_id", item_id] }` is the part that does the trick. Thanks!